# How can I determine whether a Java class is abstract by reflection

Tags: java, class, abstract

I am interating through classes in a Jar file and wish to find those which are not abstract. I can solve this by instantiating the classes and trapping InstantiationException but that has a performance hit as some classes have heavy startup. I can't find anything obviously like isAbstract() in the Class.java docs.

Answer (score 346, accepted):

It'll have abstract as one of its modifiers when you call getModifiers() on the class object.

This [link](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/class/classModifiers.html) should help.

```
 Modifier.isAbstract( someClass.getModifiers() );
```

Also:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getModifiers()

Comment: Thanks! One little note: You can't use "class" as a variable name, maybe you want to change your example.

Comment: @seth I think it should be `Modifier.isAbstract( someClass.class.getModifiers() );` maybe you want to change that

Comment: According to normal Java naming conventions it is either `someClass.getModifiers()` or `SomeClass.class.getModifiers()` where `Class<SomeClass> someClass = SomeClass.class;`

Answer (score 35):

```
Class myClass = myJar.load("classname");
bool test = Modifier.isAbstract(myClass.getModifiers());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static boolean isInstantiable(Class<?> clz) {
    if(clz.isPrimitive() || Modifier.isAbstract( clz.getModifiers()) ||clz.isInterface()  || clz.isArray() || String.class.getName().equals(clz.getName()) || Integer.class.getName().equals(clz.getName())){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: if it is a interface and class name is java.util.List you might as will create ArrayList