# How to tell if a Java class is abstract?

Tags: java, abstract-class

Is there a way programmitcally to tell if a Java class is abstract? (Other than trying to instantiate and catching the error) Thanks!

Comment: Why would you care? (A failure to construct an instance may be for a number of reasons.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I determine whether a Java class is abstract by reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072890/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-java-class-is-abstract-by-reflection)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use reflection:

```
if (Modifier.isAbstract(FooBar.class.getModifiers())) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Same answer (+interesting link) here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072890/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-java-class-is-abstract-by-reflection