# Listing abstract classes within a Java package

Tags: java, abstract-class, java-package

Is there any way to list all abstract classes within a java package? For example, in java.lang package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Guava's [`ClassPath`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.html) class you can list all top level classes in a package. You can then use the [`Modifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html) class to find out if the class is `abstract`.

Here's a small example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ClassPath p = ClassPath.from(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()); // might need to provide different ClassLoader
    ImmutableSet<ClassInfo> classes = p.getTopLevelClasses("com.example");

    for (ClassInfo classInfo : classes) {
        Class clazz = classInfo.load();
        int modifiers = clazz.getModifiers();
        if (Modifier.isAbstract(modifiers)) {
            System.out.println("Class '" + clazz.getName() + "' is abstract.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

via reflection get the list of classes int the package, and then check if the class is abstract by doing

```
Modifier.isAbstract( theClass.getModifiers() );
```

[Can you find all classes in a package using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection)

[How can I determine whether a Java class is abstract by reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072890/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-java-class-is-abstract-by-reflection)