# How do I get only instantiable classes with reflections

Tags: java, reflection, reflections

I am using the [reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) package to get a set of classes that implement a certain interface. This set will be used as a list of possible command line options. My problem is that I only want to get instantiable classes, but right now get both instantiable and non-instantiable classes (e.g. abstract classes) from the following code:

```
Map<String, Class<? extends InterfaceOptimizer>> optimizerList = new HashMap<String, Class<? extends InterfaceOptimizer>>();

Reflections reflections = new Reflections("eva2.optimization.strategies");
Set<Class<? extends InterfaceOptimizer>> optimizers = reflections.getSubTypesOf(InterfaceOptimizer.class);
for(Class<? extends InterfaceOptimizer> optimizer : optimizers) {
    optimizerList.put(optimizer.getName(), optimizer);
}
```

Is there a way to filter the set returned by `getSubTypesOf` to filter out the abstract classes?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072890/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-java-class-is-abstract-by-reflection

Comment: @rusmus, I specifically asked for non-instantiable classes and abstract classes are only one example of that. Granted, the question you linked covers abstract classes pretty well, but I didn't know how to check for interfaces.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. It asked about Reflections (and gave a link), not reflection.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the `isInterface()` method to differentiate between classes and interfaces.

Use `Modifier.isAbstract( getClass().getModifiers() );` to tell whether the class is `abstract` or not.

Comment: if(Modifier.isAbstract( myclass.getModifiers() ) || myclass.isInterface())

Answer (score 8):

You can try this

```
cls.getModifiers() & Modifier.ABSTRACT == 0 && !cls.isInterface()
```

besides it makes sense to check if the class has a no-args constructor

Comment: Thanks! Would love to accept your answer as well, but picked Adams simply because I prefer the isAbstract method.