# usage of generics as return type

Tags: java, generics, return, type-safety

I've a structure like this:

```
abstract class MyDomain{...}
abstract class FooDomain extends MyDomain{...}
abstract class BarDomain extends MyDomain{...}
class FirstConcreteBarDomain extends BarDomain{...}
class SecondConcreteBarDomain extends BarDomain{...}
```

I need a factory that creates `MyDomain` objects. My first attempt was this:

```
public interface ISpecializedObjectsFactory {
    public <T extends MyDomain> T create(Class<?> clazz);
}
```

Implementend as:

```
public class FirstSpecializedObjectsFactory implements ISpecializedObjectsFactory {

    @Override
    public <T extends MyDomain> T create(Class<?> clazz) {
        if(clazz.equals(BarDomain.class))
            return new FirstBarDomain();
        throw new InvalidParameterException();
    }
```

Same for the `SecondBarDomain`.

**FIRST QUESTION:** Why this is generating an error that says that it cannot cast `FirstBarDomain` to `T`?

After this error I've introduced a cast: `return (T) new FirstBarDomain();`.

The problem is that the cast is unsafe and I want to be confident for the result, so I've introduced another constraint (assuming that each `MyDomain` object have always 2 levels of derivation):

```
public <T extends AnagrafeDomain, S extends T> S create(Class<T> clazz)
```

**SECOND QUESTION:** Assuming that this factory is the only entry point where `MyDomain` objects are created, and that the calls to the factory never use the concrete classes (but are always like: `BarDomain subj = SpecializedObjectsFactory.getFactory().create(BarDomain.class);`), the question is: is this new version safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the cast is unsafe is because of this particular line:

```
public <T extends MyDomain> T create(Class<?> clazz) {
```

This infers the return type from the **call site**; in other words, consider the following class:

```
public abstract class MyFakeDomain extends MyDomain { }
```

The following code will then compile, but fail at runtime:

```
ISpecializedObjectsFactory factory = new FirstSpecializedObjectsFactory();
MyFakeDomain broken = factory.create(BarDomain.class);
```

This will throw a [ClassCastException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) because of the type inference; the inferred type will be `MyFakeDomain`, resulting in an attempt to cast `FirstBarDomain` to `MyFakeDomain`, which is an illegal cast - hence the unsafe warning.

The type inference is also the reason why the cast must be present; whilst `FirstBarDomain` is definitely a subclass of `MyDomain`, we do not know if it is of type `T`, as `T` could be **any** `MyDomain` subclass, not necessarily `FirstBarDomain`.

However, if the caller is careful, your code will work fine - whether you consider this acceptable or not is up to you.

This gives us the answer to your second question: using `BarDomain` as the type to be inferred will not always be safe, as it could be another subclass of `MyDomain`. The only type that would be always safe here is `MyDomain` - however, if you are planning on only using `MyDomain` as the type, you might as well remove the generic type bound and just make the return type `MyDomain`.

Comment: OP said "calls to the factory never use the concrete classes"

Comment: @sharonbn Correct, but that still doesn't make it safe though; even if ```MyFakeDomain``` is ```abstract```, it will still result in the exact same problem. I will explicitly make it abstract to avoid confusion.

Comment: This would and should through a class cast exception. Surely you would use the `BarDomain` interface to decouple code from spesific implementation. Just like you would rather `List<Object> = ...` rather than `ArrayList<Object> = ...`

Comment: @Ian2thedv Sorry, I don't understand your comment. My point is that the above code will throw a ClassCastException, as part of the explanation of why the code in the OP is unsafe.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I don't understand **why** someone would assign the variable to an implementation type. You would assign it to the interface type, which is `BarDomain`, not `MyFakeDomain` or any other class extending `BarDomain` without an `interfaceof` check.

Comment: Please note that I am not endorsing using a concrete type - I very much agree that the type should be an interface type (well, abstract class in this case). I am explaining why the Java compiler considers the code in the OP unsafe, which is irrelevant to whether or not it is **used** safely (as would be the case if using an appropriate interface type).

Comment: +1 for actually explain what I didn't consider for my first question. I suppose that the only solution to have a 100% safe code is to have a method for each posible return type instead of a switch inside the create method.

Answer (score 0):

The constraint that will give you the confidence you are looking for is limiting the classes that your factory receives:

```
public interface ISpecializedObjectsFactory {
    public <T extends MyDomain> T create(Class<? extends MyDomain> clazz);
}


public class FirstSpecializedObjectsFactory implements ISpecializedObjectsFactory {
    @Override
    public <T extends MyDomain> T create(Class<? extends MyDomain> clazz) {
        if(clazz.equals(BarDomain.class))
            return (T) new FirstBarDomain();
        throw new InvalidParameterException();
    }
}
```

The compiler will not accept any call to create when the argument is not a subclass of MyDomain.  However, it will accept an abstract class. If you want to know you received a concrete class, you can find the answer here [How can I determine whether a Java class is abstract by reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072890/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-java-class-is-abstract-by-reflection)

Comment: I think that this solution will accept `FooDomain subj = SpecializedObjectsFactory.getFactory().create(BarDomain.class);` and it will throw a classCastException